# Jquery each inside onclick event

Tags: jquery, razor, click, each

Razor/HTML (many of these):

```
<div class="directory-item" id="@item_id" name="@item_name" style="padding-left: @(indent_level)px;  display: @(display)">
   <i class="fa @icon_type"></i>
   @item.ItemName (id: @item_id, name: @item_name, level: @item.Level)
   <i class="fa  fa-angle-right float-right"></i>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".directory-item").click(function () {
    $('div[name*=' + this.id + ']').each(function () {
        if (this.attr('display') == "none") {
            this.show();
        } else {
            this.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Basic question: how do you put an "each" inside a "click" event and reference the "each" item (each time it accesses an element) with "this"? Maybe I shouldn't be using an each statement but something else?

Comment: yes.you should use `this` or even the jQuery wrapped item of that `$(this)` to access the clicked item. Then you can access relative items using methods like `closest()` ,`find` etc

Comment: How would you rewrite the above using find? Basically, I'm trying to take the id of the div that was clicked, and find all divs with name containing that id, then show/hide toggle them.

Comment: You should not have more than one item with the same Id value! That is invalid html. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I don't, look again... I have one id from the item click, then I use that idem to find all items that CONTAIN the same NAME, not id.

Comment: I see. `this.id` will give you the clicked item's id.

Answer (score 1):

In the each method's callback, you can have 2 parameters, one for the index and second for the item of current iteration of the loop.

```
$(function () {

    $(".directory-item").click(function () {

        $('div[name*=' + this.id + ']').each(function (a,b) {
            if ($(b).attr('display') == "none") {
                $(b).show();
            } else {
                $(b).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If it simply updating the visibility, you can use `toggle` as well

```
$('div[name*=' + this.id + ']').each(function (a,b) {
    $(b).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are elements with names that do match the id of element clicked you should be able to simplify this to:

```
$(".directory-item").click(function () {
        $('div[name*=' + this.id + ']').toggle()
});
```

Using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show such element if it is hidden and hide it if it is not and there is no need for `each` as it will loop through all matching elements internally